# B+Tree height assessment

Tags: b-tree

Say I have a B+ tree with branching factor b=10. I want to put inside n=9000 items. I calculated the height to be 4-6, persuming that the root is full.

If I make the root width only 1 item, can I assume that I have 2 B+ trees of 4500 items each to get a height of 5-7?

Comment: Are you currently taking the exam? :)

Comment: lol .. no, though this would have been a nice idea..